# using row_num() and using filtering value from window function in WHERE CLAUSE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, window-functions, row-number

I have stored procedure.SELECT statement is like below

```
select  
*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ProductRN.ID) as RNN
from  (
SELECT 

p.ID
,p.ProductCode
,p.ProductNameF
,p.ProductNameE
,p.[Weight]
,p.PackageTypeID
,p.ISForeign
,p.BrandID
,b.BrandNameF
,b.BrandNameE
,p.ImgID
,p.CategoryID
,p.AmountInBox
,pc.PropertyGroupID
,p.Comment
,p.CompanyID
,p.Status
,po.CompanyNameF
,PriceConsumer=MKT.Fn_GetProductPrice(1,p.ID, @CurDate)
,PriceRetail=MKT.Fn_GetProductPrice(2,p.ID, @CurDate)
,PriceWholesale=MKT.Fn_GetProductPrice(3,p.ID, @CurDate)
,pg.PropertyName as PropertyGroupName
,b.LogoID
from mkt.Product as p (nolock)
inner join mkt.ProductCategory as pc (nolock) on pc.ID = p.CategoryID
inner join mkt.Brand b (nolock) on p.BrandID=b.ID
inner join MKT.ProductOwner as po (nolock) on po.ID = b.BrandOwnerID
left  join MKT.PropertyGroup as pg (nolock) on pc.PropertyGroupID=pg.ID

) AS  ProductRN 

where ProductRN.CompanyID=@CompanyID 
and  ProductRN.Status=1 
and  ProductRN.CategoryID=@ProductCategoryID
AND  (ProductRN.BrandID=@BrandID OR @BrandID=0)
--SOME WAY TO FILTER RNN

end
```

there is not any way to use RNN Column in WHERE CLAUSE because we can't use Column aliases and window function inside WHERE CLAUSE. 
actually the problem is that when i put

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ProductRN.ID) as RNN
```

inside inner SELECT statement, RNN column exactly become equal to   p.ID (Product.ID) it seems sql server first calculates row_number() and then perform the WHERE CLAUSE.

How can I change this query so that row_num() apply to final query records
and I can filter it in WHERE CLAUSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery or CTE:

```
select t.*
from (<your query goes here>) t
where rnn = 1;
```

Comment: it works. 
thank you very much. but dose using  multiple nested select statement make query slow? is there any fast way?